# Parallelise OCR by sending blocks/ paragraphs of text

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I am looking to increase the speed of performing OCR on a text image by sending blocks of text separately to OCR instead of sending one text image. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order to cut out your input image, you need to detect the lines of text. It should be easy enough if it is typed and the lines are mostly straight. Scans that are not straight or hand written which are going up and down won't be easy to deal with! One last word of caution: only scans at higher DPI will cooperate in this situation (I would say at least 300 DPI).

Otherwise it is a matter of finding a "non white" line scanning from the top, that's where your first line starts, then finding the next "white line", that's the vertical end of your line.

However... OCR does not just scan the image, it interpret the results. So if your line ends with a partial word ("extrac-") it is capable of finding the end of the word ("-ting") at the beginning of the next line.

If you cut and attempt to process the lines one by one, you'll miss all of those (which in many documents aren't used so you may be just fine.)

---

What is a "white line"?

Here I assume that your documents are black ink on white paper. When you scan a document, the white paper appears as light gray in your image. The idea is pretty simple: compute the average of X number of pixels and see how light or dark they are, if light enough, then consider that to be white.

```
quick_gray = (r + g + b) / 3;  // this is not a correct gray computation, but good enough here (and relatively fast.)

average = (qg1 + qg2 + qg3 + ... + qgN) / N;  // the average of 9 or 25 pixels

if(average < 40) { goto white_pixel; }
```

The divisions can be skipped to make things go faster since you can rewrite the average test as:

```
if(average < 40 * 3 * N) { ... }
```

That's assuming quick_gray and average are types large enough to support the (much larger) computation results.

As you can see, this determines whether a PIXEL is white, not a line. You have to repeat that math for each pixel of the whole line to know whether the whole thing is white.

The pixel in question is the X in the following and the * represent the area check (N = 5 x 5 = 25 pixels.)

```
o o o o o o o o o
o o * * * * * o o
o o * * * * * o o
o o * * X * * o o
o o * * * * * o o
o o * * * * * o o
o o o o o o o o o
```

It is also possible to use a weight system where pixels further away from the center do not affect the result as much. So the * right around the X could be given a weight of 0.9 and the ones further away give a weight of 0.5. That way the * that are further away can be twice darker and X would still be considered white.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking up some C++ CUDA examples to get the basic idea of parallel programming syntax.

http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/my-first-cuda-program/

This link may help you out here.

Decide how your planning to split up your text and then pass it all into a CUDA kernel with as many threads/blocks you require and perform the OCR in there.

I'm afraid with such little information you have provided I can't really be much more help than that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the link is broken. Also, my question was how to decide to split my image and not how to pass it to kernels.